# How do I avoid boxing/unboxing when extending System.Object?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, boxing, unboxing

I'm working on an extension method that's only applicable to reference types.  I think, however, it's currently boxing and unboxing the the value.  How can I avoid this?

```
namespace System
{
    public static class SystemExtensions
    {
        public static TResult GetOrDefaultIfNull<T, TResult>(this T obj, Func<T, TResult> getValue, TResult defaultValue)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return defaultValue;
            return getValue(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

In some method:

```
Foo aFooObject = new Foo { Bar = 1 };
Foo nullReference = null;

Console.WriteLine(aFooObject.GetOrDefaultIfNull((o) => o.Bar, 0));  // results: 1
Console.WriteLine(nullReference.GetOrDefaultIfNull((o) => o.Bar, 0));  // results: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not boxing. Where do you think it *is* boxing? If it's because you've looked at the IL around "==", don't let it fool you - the JIT gets to decide what to do here. It has the chance to generate different native code for each (`T`, `TResult`) pair. In fact, the code will be shared for all reference types, and differ for value types. So you'd end up with:

```
T = string, TResult = int (native code #1)
T = Stream, TResult = byte (native code #2)
T = string, TResult = byte (native code #2)
T = Stream, TResult = string (native code #3)
```

Having said that, if you want to restrict your extension method to reference types, do so:

```
public static TResult GetOrDefaultIfNull<T, TResult>
    (this T obj, Func<T, TResult> getValue, TResult defaultValue)
    where T : class
```

There'll still be a box in the IL, but don't worry - no boxing will actually occur. After all, what *could* be boxed? You're providing a reference, and references themselves are never boxed - only value type values are boxed.

Comment: Interesting that's it's not boxing.  This code compiled:
            int i = 1;
            i.GetOrDefaultIfNull((o) => o.ToString(), "");
Thanks for the "where T : class" as that's really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, there is nothing in that code that would require boxing. There *are* scenarios where boxing is unavoidable, and there are also additional opcodes for bridging the gap between value/ref types ([`constrained`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx)) in some cases.

But not in this case; no *actual* boxing required (the JIT can remove a few box-like cases - but not all, sadly)